# ObjectMapper displayed model in TableView Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am new to Swift , i parsing my JSON by using ObjectMapper but I want data displayed in TableView 
I do not know how to do that

My Model:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import SwiftyJSON

class AllCnannelModel : Mappable {

    var  id : Int?
    var  name: String?
    var  url : URL?
    var  picture : URL?
    var  category_id: Int?

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id<-map["id"]
        name<-map["name"]
        url<-map["url"]
        picture<-map["picture"]
        category_id<-map["category_id"]
    }
}
```

My TableView :

```
var name = [String]()

var urlChannel = [URL]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            let URL = "http://52.50.138.211:8080/ChanelAPI/chanels"

    Alamofire.request(URL).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[AllCnannelModel]>) in

        let channnellArray = response.result.value

        if let channnellArray = channnellArray {
            for channel in channnellArray {

                self.name.append(channel.name!)
            }

        }
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I can describe one type of data in the array and display:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
      return self.name.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.name[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

but i want all type of data in one array and display TableViewController 
How can you implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implemented `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` ?

Comment: yes    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 5
    }

Comment: I think you want to use one section. But thats not the case. You dont have to creat array name, just create variable that stores whole Model. Please also check if UITableView dataSource is correctly assigned. If you are using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController you need to asign dataSource explicit by calling 'tableView.dataSource = self' or connecting outlet in storyboard.

Comment: How can I create a variable ?

Comment: Just define 'var channels = [AllCnannelModel]()' and then instead of iterating  channnellArray just assign it like that 'channels = channnellArray' and call reloadData() on tableView. Please notice that you need to also modify line where you are setting text on cell, now you need to get channel object and then get its name. Good luck!